# Reply To SMS Message: What is the difference between "compose_mode" = true vs false?

Tags: android, sms

Using the code below or similar, what does the flag "compose_mode" do in regard to replying to an SMS message?

Example Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + sendTo));
intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true); //What does this line do? What if it was "false"?
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but discovered that:

```
// Exit the app once the SMS is sent
    intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
```

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/ResultHandler.java?r=635

Comment: I saw this online as well, but I am looking for an explanation of what it really means. Maybe someone who has experience with using this in both manors as well as an explanation of its usage in different scenarios.